# How to convert an integer to a c-string and vice versa and other datatypes without using any in-built functions?

Tags: c, arrays, string, function

I don't understand the basic concept of it.

Comment: Not even close.  Talk to your prof/TA.   You need tuition, not an SO question.

Comment: No functions are "built-in" in C, presumably you mean without using standard library or third-party functions?  A string is a sequence of _characters_, while an integer is a binary value. Translating from one to the other is clearly not as simple as your naive suggestion.  As a CS student, this is what your course tutor should be teaching you - it is pretty fundamental stuff - not to C, but to computing in general..

Comment: You have made the question worse in the edit - do not ask a different question in the title than the body, and do not ask more than one question at a time.  It already has close votes for lack of focus, and now you have made it worse.  Your change renders existing answers (and any answers someone might have been in the process of writing) nonsense.

Comment: @Clifford and the rest, thank you! It hasn't been a while into my studies, so I just forgot that concept. What if we have to convert float into an integer? How do I change the memory allocation?

Comment: What does memory allocation have to do with this question?

Comment: okay... so i simply truncate the decimal value?

Comment: What?!  No! How did you come to that conclusion?  Did you try it?  Does it work? Start again, and show some effort or example in code of what you are trying to achieve - it is much less likely to then get closed than if you appear to be attempting to get your homework done for free.

Comment: Values in computers are represented using bits. Most often, eight bits are grouped together and called a byte. In C, a `char` is a byte that represents a character. A C string is a sequence of bytes (contained in an array) that ends with a byte with value zero. Positive integers are represented using binary. Often, the `int` type in C is four bytes (32 bits). To convert from a decimal numeral in a C string, you write software code that examines the characters in a string, computes the value represented, and puts the result in an `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string in C is a sequence of character values including a zero-valued terminator - the string `"1234"` is represented as the character sequence `{'1', '2', '3', '4', 0}`.  Assuming ASCII encodings, that’s a byte sequence of `{0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x00}`.

An integer value in C is a standard binary representation.  Assuming a 32-bit integer, the value `1234` is represented as `0x000004d2` - not anywhere similar to the string representation.

Converting a string representation of a decimal integer (`"1234"`) to an integer value is fairly straightforward:

```
int result = 0;
char *p = "1234";

while ( *p )  // while we haven’t reached the end of the string
{
  result *= 10;           // shift our result by 1 digit left
  result += (*p++ - '0')  // convert the current character 
                          // to its decimal equivalent and 
                          // add to the result, and advance 
                          // p to point to the next character
}
```

So as we process the string `"1234"`, we get

```
result = 0            // 0
result = 10 * 0 + 1   // 1
result = 10 * 1 + 2   // 12
result = 10 * 12 + 3  // 123
result = 10 * 123 + 4 // 1234
```

The C standard mandates that decimal digit encodings be sequential, so `'1' - '0'` yields `1`, `'2' - '0'` yields `2`, etc.

Going the other way (integer to string) is a little more involved.  You have to make sure your target buffer is large enough to hold the string, including a sign and the terminator.  It takes a little over 3 bits on average to represent a decimal digit, so a 32-bit integer could potentially represent 10 decimal digits. Your target buffer would need to be at least 12 characters wide to account for a possible sign and the terminator.

You can get the individual decimal digits from right to left by successively dividing the integer value by 10:

```
char target[14] = {0};
int value = 1234;
size_t end = 4; // this is a cheat
while ( value )
{
  digit = value % 10;   // isolate the least significant digit
  value /= 10;          // shift value one digit right
  char c = '0' + digit; // convert digit to character
  target[––end] = c;    // add the digit to the string.
}
```

I’m cheating a bit since I know how many digits to convert ahead of time - in the general case, you’d have to figure out how many digits to account for, and whether or not you have to take the sign into account.

Comment: Given that a 32 bit integer for example can be no more than 10 digits a simple solution is to start with `end = sizeof(target) - 1`, and use the string `&target[end + 1]` rather than `target`.

Answer (score 0):

```
4567
```

means

```
4 * 10^3 + 5 * 10^2 + 6 * 10^1 + 7 * 10^0
```

This can also be written as

```
( ( 4 * 10 + 5 ) * 10 + 6 ) * 10 + 7
```

If the number is formed by repeatedly multiplying by 10, that means that taking it apart is done by repeatedly dividing by 10.

```
4567/10 = 456 + 7/10
 456/10 =  45 + 6/10
  45/10 =   4 + 5/10
   4/10 =   0 + 4/10
```

The remainder of these divisions, once added to `'0'`, will given the digits of your string.